# Unable to download an older version of TensorFlow

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to download Tensor Flow version 1.8.0
I have tried the command:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.8.0
```

and

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.8.0
```

and uninstalling and re installing TF and rerunning the same commands. Each time I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.8.0 (from versions: 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.8.0
```

also, what does it mean "from versions: 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0" in the error? I thought it is possible to download older versions?

I am using a Mac.

Comment: You will need to specify a compatible python you want to install to.   `/path/to/python -m pip install tensorflow==1.8.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using python version > 3.6, then these version are not compatible with tensorflow 1.8.0 version.

this is why you are getting the error. package version which are shown in error message are the version supported by python that you are using.

inorder to use this package you need to downgrade your python environment to 3.6 or less.